Default OS is Grub. Send help
When I power on my computer ( 2013 imac ) with ubunut 20.04
The default os is right away GRUB command. I did some boo boos and would like to make it boot up normal. And want to reinstall ubuntu as I accidently erased python.
What are the steps to wipe the drive and start over? The Mac OS is erased so it's just Ubuntu

It's not clear to me in what state you're actually in, possibly you're describing a non-bootable system that leaves you in grub rescue, but other things you say imply its something else. We need to understand fully where you are, and what you're actually running in order to fix things. You can non-destructively re-install some systems (esp. desktop) rather easily & not lose data;  but you only mention release (20.04) and not product (server, desktop etc). You can also usually re-install python3-minimal even if you need to avoid easier tools like apt too.

Do you want to reinstall the whole operating system because you deleted python? To me, all you need to do is use a bootable Linux and fix your grub.

So @guiverc,  I ended up erasing python on my computer. ( long story ) so then I looked on google and followed some youtibe videos of how to get it back. Which  made everything worse. App store didn't work terminal didn't work. Update didn't work. File folders doesn't work. Apt get-updates give errors. Its a gong show. Then what happened was I somehow made it so it boots up only to grub command. But with some code I can make ubunut be normal again until the next reboot then back to the grub command

@DanielN. I did multiple things, used xut ( since terminal wont work now that I don't gave python 3.8 ) to try to reinstall and make it default but it won't accept it. Keeps saying in the UT error with file. At this stage I would like to know how to boot up the computer into a state where I can apply my USB since I have ubuntu on it. When I hit escape on boot up nothing happens because boot up is already in grub command by default

Many Ubuntu Desktop apps rely on the default python3 installed with your system, so if you remove python3 those apps won't work (or if default version is changed; they can not work properly and cause corruption, which though rare, is actually worse). Base tools will still work, from text terminal (ie. treat system as if a server) but user-friendly tools that rely on python3 won't. Removing python3 (or changing version) is a bad move; esp. on desktop systems.

You can non-destructively re-install a Ubuntu Desktop system, which is a quick/easy fix, but you really only need to re-install python3-minimal before the system will be mostly usable again (it needs to be the correct version though for your release).

I see, then I would say, use SystemRescueCD to boot up (you have to configure the boot order sequence in your BIOS, or depending on the machine hitting F2 or F12 will give you a menu of bootable options).
Once there, fix your grub, and secondly chroot into your Ubuntu and install python.
However, I don't think you are in the level to do that, so probably you're right about reinstalling the whole system might be the best option for you.
I have never owned a Mac, so I'm not sure how you could boot to your USB.

I don't see anything in the description that would require a special "wipe the drive."

The term "wipe" often means a process of making data unrecoverable, which is not necessary for most users. You're not a bank or government preventing theft of sensitive information, so it seems unlikely you meant that process in this case.

Simply boot from any Ubuntu USB installer and follow the prompts to reinstall Ubuntu. The normal Ubuntu installer will re-format your system's storage device (drive), allowing you to start clean.
If you still have your original USB installer, you can use that. Or you can make a new one. They all work.
